# How to update data in objectbox flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-objectbox

I was using ObjectBox for storing data. But how to update the same data. In documentation, it says  it will update the data. But When I pass an old note with some new details, it create new note.

```
 Future<int> createNotes(Note note) async {
    var store = await BoxStore.getStore();
    var box = store.box<Note>();
    int id = box.put(note);
    print('note id: $id');
    store.close();
    return id;
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you provide looks like creating a new note.

ObjectBox updates a record if it finds the field `id` in its internal table key, otherwise it creates a new record. So either you store the note id inside `Note note` when getting the note from ObjectBox and use it when updating, or if you are using some kind of an own id, then - upon storing - first get the ObjectBox internal id by creating a query on your own id and use this id to `put` the note as an update

Comment: Additionally, if you print `note.id` after `box.put()`, you'll see it equals `id`. So basically to update, you can use the same object later on, change whatever you need, and do `box.put()` again.

Answer (score 0):

To update some column or groups you do it with the put example:

```
var query2 = _stores.box<Documentos>().query(Documentos_.numero.oneOf(send)).build();

for (var w in query2.find().toList()) {
      w.enviado = 1;
      _stores.box<Documentos>().put(w);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the thread is old but let me still put my contribution. you might be intrested in updating single Object
`Box<ItemModel>(_stores!).put(ItemModel, mode: PutMode.update);`
The default put gives you previlege to insert and update as the same time